# The roots of the cubic equation, $2x^3+px^2-(3+5i)x+q=0$ are $x\in \{ i , \frac{1}{k}, -1-k\} $ Find $p,q$ and $k$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> > The roots of the cubic equation, $2x^3+px^2-(3+5i)x+q=0$ are $x\in \{ i , \frac{1}{k}, -1-k\} $
> >
> > Use this information to find $p,q$ and $k$, where $k$ is real.

What I have done:

Consider $p(x)=2x^3+px^2+(-3-5i)x+q=0$

Since $x=i$ , $x=\frac{1}{k}$ and $x=-1-k$ are roots we will try subbing them in and seperating imaginary and real parts and solving simultaneously hopefully!

Starting of with $x=i$

$$\Longrightarrow p(i)=2(i)^3+p(i)^2+(-3-5i)i+q=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow -2i -p +5 - 3i +q=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow q-p+5-5i=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (q-p+5)+i(-5)=0$$

So one equation we have is $q-p+5=0$

Next $x=\frac{1}{k}$

$$\Longrightarrow p(\frac{1}{k})=2(\frac{1}{k})^3+p(\frac{1}{k})^2+(-3-5i)\frac{1}{k}+q=0$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{k^3} + \frac{p}{k^2} - \frac{3}{k} - \frac{5i}{k}+q=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (\frac{2}{k^3} + \frac{p}{k^2} - \frac{3}{k} +q) + i(\frac{-5}{k})=0$$

So another equation we have is $\frac{2}{k^3} + \frac{p}{k^2} - \frac{3}{k} +q=0$ since $\frac{-5}{k} \neq 0$

The last root we have is $x=-1-k$

$$\Longrightarrow p(-1-k)=2(-1-k)^3+p(-1-k)^2+(-3-5i)(-1-k)+q=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow -2(k+1)^3+p(k+1)^2+3+3k+5i+5ki+q=0 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (-2(k+1)^3+p(k+1)^2+3+3k+q)+i(5+5k) =0 $$

So 2 other equations we have are $-2(k+1)^3+p(k+1)^2+3+3k+q=0$ and $5+5k=0$

Hence the 4 equations we have are

$$q-p+5=0 $$

$$\frac{2}{k^3} + \frac{p}{k^2} - \frac{3}{k} +q=0$$

$$-2(k+1)^3+p(k+1)^2+3+3k+q=0$$

$$5+5k=0$$

For the last equation $k=-1$ and subbing this into the third equation I get $q=0$
and subbing that into the second equation I get $p=1$ but subbing $q$ and $p$ into $q-p+5$ does not make it true so where did I go wrong? I also do not think I have made any algebraic error.

Comment: Note that since the roots of the given polynomial are what they are, the polynomial can be written as $2(x-i)\left(x-\frac 1k\right)(x+k+1)$. Now the independent term of this polynomial is $-i\cdot \frac 1 k\cdot (k+1)\color{grey}{=q}$. So $q$ can't be null. This doesn't tell you where you went wrong, but it suggests an alternative way of solving the problem and it tells you where you can start looking for your mistake.

Comment: @GitGud Yes for sure, I used that method but I was wondering why my way of approaching the question didn't initially work?

Comment: I didn't want to read through all that. But luckily I stumbled on one mistake: "So one equation we have is $q-p+5=0$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via long division of the polynomial by $x-i$ we get
$$2x^3-px^2-(3+5i)x+q=(x-i)(2x^2+(p-2i)x+(-1+(p-5)i)$$
Immediately we run into an error in your working, since $q=i+(p-5)$, not $q-p+5=0$. Rewinding to the line where this false relation is introduced:
$$(q-p+5)+i(-5)=0$$
we see that going from this to $q-p+5=0$ implies that $-5i=0$, which is absurd.

The other relations you derive (with $x=\frac1k,-1-k$) are also flawed. The correct equations those *incorrect* relations stem from:
$$\left(\frac{2}{k^3} + \frac{p}{k^2} - \frac{3}{k} +q\right) + i\left(\frac{-5}{k}\right)=0$$
$$(-2(k+1)^3+p(k+1)^2+3+3k+q)+i(5+5k) =0$$
are of the form $a+bi=0$, but **you cannot say that $a=0$ or $b=0$ in this case** as you did because $a$ and $b$ can be complex here. They need to be restricted to the real numbers in order for you to conclude that $a=b=0$.

We shall solve for $p,q,k$ anyway. The remaining roots after the long division are all real, so the coefficients of the quotient polynomial must be too. $p-2i$ real implies $p=a+2i$ with $a$ real. $-1+(p-5)i=-3+(a-5)i$ is also real, so $a=5$, $p=5+2i$ and our remaining quadratic equation is
$$2x^2+5x-3=0$$
which turns out to have roots $\frac12$ and $-3$, so $k=2$. $q$ works out to be $i+(5+2i-5)=3i$.